# Unable to run code in screen

Tags: bash, ubuntu, xvfb

I have following code to execute some commands on a virtue screen:

```
screen -R << EOF
    cd /home/users/devops_tester/apps/Selenium-Webdriver
    export DISPLAY=:99
    npm start
EOF
```

It gives me an error:

```
Must be connected to a terminal.
```

How can I solve it?

I found this related topics but I am not using ssh:

https://serverfault.com/questions/21806/how-can-i-launch-a-screen-session-with-a-command-over-ssh-on-a-remote-server-fro

This is the screen app:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/screen

Comment: What is a *"virtue screen"* ?

Comment: I use xvfb to run some selenium test headlessly. @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: Seems like the process is running in the background and needs a foreground session